# How to change a class based on the date using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating an advent calendar and I need a piece of jQuery/Javascript that will change the class on a div based on the date.

I need all previous days to have one class, the present day one class and future dates one class.

This is my source code:

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="box nov28">...</div>
        <div class="box dec1">...</div>
        <div class="box dec3">...</div>
        <div class="box dec5">...</div>
        <div class="box dec7">...</div>
        <div class="box dec12">...</div>
        <div class="box dec15">...</div>
        <div class="box dec17">...</div>
        <div class="box dec19">...</div>
        <div class="box dec21">...</div>
        <div class="box dec22">...</div>
        <div class="box dec23">...</div>
    </div>
```

It's not a simple begin 1st December and proceed for 24 days. There are 12 days of 'offers' which will not follow on exactly. This can be seen by the div classes i.e. nov28 dec1 dec3

On the class days I need the class present to be added, on previous days - the class previous and on future dates - the class future.

All help appreciated.

--EDIT --

Original post amended to be more specific.

Comment: Have you any code at all? What is the formatting of the dates you have and the classes you want etc.

Comment: How do you identify the date of a div? You might want to post the html of the calendar you are generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the html code above

```
var today = new Date();
today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

var month = "dec";
var day = today.getDate();
if (today.getMonth() == 10) {
    month="nov";
}

var selected = $(".container > div."+month+day);
if (selected.size() > 0) {
    selected.prevAll("div").addClass("previous");
    selected.addClass("present");
    selected.nextAll("div").addClass("future");
} else {
    // based on idea from Russ Cam but
    // only loop over all div's if today there is no matching div
    // as this is more costly (loop, regex, ...)
    $('.container > div').each(function() {
        var div = $(this);
        //extract month and date from class value 
        var divMonth = div.attr("class").replace(/.*(nov|dec)\d+.*/, "$1") == 'nov' ? 10 : 11;
        var divDay = div.attr("class").replace(/.*(?:nov|dec)(\d+).*/, "$1");
        var divDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), divMonth, divDay);
        if (divDate > today)
            div.addClass('future');
        else
            if (divDate < today)
                div.addClass('previous');
            else
                div.addClass('present');
    });
}
```

Check http://jsbin.com/ewuro/edit for the demonstration code (little bit adapted to show it off). Click the output tab to try it out.

Btw. <strike>http://jsbin.com/ewuro</strike>, although it should show the same as http://jsbin.com/ewuro/edit -> Output tab, doesn't work. As the framework behind jsbin seems to swallow the `$1` in my regex thus the three buttons for (Nov27, Dec4 and Dec8 won't work). So just try it in the outputtab.

Comment: Hi I've added more info in the original question, I'm not great with Javascript, would your suggestion still work?

Comment: I reworked my solution to fit your problem. Works only for november and december. Also able to handle the gap-days where no div exists.

Comment: Hi, I've added your code to my page and it's still not adding the classes to the div. Any idea?

Comment: #1: Did you try the jsbin.com/ewuro/edit -> output tab? Does it work there for you?
#2 Did you include jquery into your page
#3 where/how did you include my script
#4 what does the error console of your browser say
#5 does your page really look like the code provided by you and are the css styles really named like what you provided

Comment: #1 yes, your example works fine, #2 yes, jquery is included in the head, #3 I've added your code inside the <script> tag, inside the <head> of my document, #4 there are no errors or warnings, #5 yes

I've got no idea why it's not working!

Comment: well when you add it in the head you should wrap the whole thing in a $(document).ready(function() {....}); thingie

Answer (score 1):

```
// get today's date
var today = new Date();
today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

// go through the calendar windows representing each day
$('div.calendar-window').each(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    // check the date of the window.
    // let's imagine that the date is in a span with class date
    var divDate = Date.parse($('span.date', this).text());
    switch(divDate)
    {
        case divDate > today:
            div.addClass('future');
            break;               
        case divDate < today:
            div.addClass('past');
            break;
        default:
            div.addClass('today');   
            break;        
    }      
});
```

That's just an example, but hopefully you get the idea. Considering an advent calendar runs only for December, using the full date might be overkill and simply using `getDate()` and doing an integer comparison may be a better approach. Furthermore, we could just select the `<span>` elements an iterate through them, applying the class to the parent `<div>` in each case. This is meant to be food for thought :)

Comment: Hi I've added more info in the original question, I'm not great with Javascript, would your suggestion still work?